# Where is wallpaper setting stored?

Tags: macos, wallpaper, sonoma

I upgraded my MacBook Pro from Ventura to Sonoma yesterday. Today I was going through System Settings, to see if there were any interesting new settings, and inadvertently changed my wallpaper.

My old wallpaper was just a solid color that I liked, but none of the choices in the current list seem to be the same. So I'd like to restore the preference file that contains the wallpaper setting from Time Machine. Does anyone know where this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Wallpaper and scroll down to Colors.

From there, just select the color you want or hit the Plus button and choose the color from the color pallet.

Comment: Finding it in the pallet will be difficult, I was hoping I could just restore it directly.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, but it's what I eventually did. I found a color in the palette that I liked better than the built-in choices.